# Postgresql Logical Replication Initial Table Sync Stage Restarting

Tags: postgresql, replication, aws-aurora

I'm using logical replication on a Postgres 10 DB (Amazon Linux 2) to Aurora Postgres 11 RDS.

There are 256 tables that need replicating and a few are pretty large (millions to 100s of millions of rows)

Watching the postgresql.log output in Cloud Watch for Aurora Postgres I can see when the synchronization workers start and finish on a per table basis

For example,

```
2020-11-05 16:09:44 UTC::@:[35430]:LOG: logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "big_kahuna", table "url" has started

... an hourish later

2020-11-05 17:04:30 UTC::@:[35430]:LOG: logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "big_kahuna", table "url" has finished
```

Some of my tables show starting again telling me it's failing and retrying

However, one in particular restarted after about 7 hours which I've been watching progress via the following query on the publishing instance.

```
SELECT datname, pid, state, query, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start) AS age 
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state <> 'idle' 
    AND query NOT LIKE '% FROM pg_stat_activity %' 
    AND query LIKE 'COPY%'
ORDER BY age;

    datname     |  pid  | state  |                      query                       |       age
----------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------
theusername     | 38228 | active | COPY public.thetable TO STDOUT                   | 07:51:48.124183
(3 rows)
```

I'm wondering what can be causing the table to have to restart the initial table sync?

I'm closely watching memory consumption and thats no where near being reached (system is at about 100 GB of 512 available RAM) and the same setup and server spec has successfully done this previously.

Comment: Are there any error messages associated with that restart? If yes, can you quote them? If not, perhaps you can set `log_min_messages` to `debug2` or so.

Comment: I never altered the logging level (worried about additional overhead and didn't want to restart server) but after 12+ hours the table did make is out of the initial synchronization stage on the third try. Circling back though, were you referring to the master or the replica?

Comment: If it fails and restarts, that should be in the log file you are already looking in.  You might need to comb through it more thoroughly.

Comment: I'd look in both log files.